# How boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor work with TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT and TCP_FASTOPEN

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

How boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor work with TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT and TCP_FASTOPEN,

When I use pure C, I can set some param like TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT and TCP_FASTOPEN, to improve tcp/ip performance,like this:
setsockopt(serverSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT, &soValue, sizeof(soValue));
setsockopt( serverSock, SOL_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen));
 But when I use boost::asio，Ｉcould not find any way to set TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT and TCP_FASTOPEN, who can tell me how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. use boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::native_handle().

example:

```
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>   sp_acceptor( std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>( d_ios_last0 ) );
sp_acceptor->open( server_endpoint.protocol() );
sp_acceptor->set_option( boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( true  ) );
if( bool_tcp_defer_accept )  {
  int soValue = 1;
  if( 0 == setsockopt( sp_acceptor->native_handle(), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT, &soValue, sizeof(soValue)) )  {
    log_message( "TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT set success." );
    }
  else  {
    warn_message( "TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT set failed." );
    }
  }
sp_acceptor->bind( server_endpoint );
if( bool_tcp_fastopen )  {
  int qlen=5;
  if( 0==setsockopt( sp_acceptor->native_handle(), SOL_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen)) ) {
    log_message( "TCP_FASTOPEN set success." );
    }
  else  {
    warn_message( "TCP_FASTOPEN set failed." );
    }
  }
sp_acceptor->listen( 8192 );
```